# Swift TensorFlowLite Interpreter Error : Type 'Interpreter' has no member 'Options'

Tags: swift, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I clone TensorFlowLite sample app for iOS from following repositery
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification/ios

Installed pod file that contains 
`pod 'TensorFlowLiteSwift'`

When I opened `ImageClassification.xcworkspace`, Xcode directly showing following error.

> Type 'Interpreter' has no member 'Options'

I did not change any code in sample application.

This error is coming while calling `Options()` of Interpreter

`var options = Interpreter.Options()`

I tried to get Option property with some other method of Interpreter but could not get it.

```
init?(modelFileInfo: FileInfo, labelsFileInfo: FileInfo, threadCount: Int = 1) {
    let modelFilename = modelFileInfo.name

    // Construct the path to the model file.
    guard let modelPath = Bundle.main.path(
      forResource: modelFilename,
      ofType: modelFileInfo.extension
    ) else {
      print("Failed to load the model file with name: \(modelFilename).")
      return nil
    }

    // Specify the options for the `Interpreter`.
    self.threadCount = threadCount
    var options = Interpreter.Options() // Here the issue is *Type 'Interpreter' has no member 'Options*
    options.threadCount = threadCount
    do {
      // Create the `Interpreter`.
      interpreter = try Interpreter(modelPath: modelPath, options: options)
      // Allocate memory for the model's input `Tensor`s.
      try interpreter.allocateTensors()
    } catch let error {
      print("Failed to create the interpreter with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      return nil
    }
    // Load the classes listed in the labels file.
    loadLabels(fileInfo: labelsFileInfo)
  }
```

This `init()` is expected to initialise & give ModelDataHandler object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Interpreter.Options()` should be changed back to `InterpreterOptions()` how it originally was in all TensorFlow Lite examples.

One of the recent commits has broken the build:
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/commit/751f4648e3917178b0e67454422477fe5d81d611

Answer (score 1):

I changed my local code to use the InterpreterOptions class.

```
    // Specify the options for the `Interpreter`.
    self.threadCount = threadCount
    var options = InterpreterOptions()
    options.threadCount = threadCount
    do {
      // Create the `Interpreter`.
      interpreter = try Interpreter(modelPath: modelPath, options: options)
      // Allocate memory for the model's input `Tensor`s.
      try interpreter.allocateTensors()
    } catch let error {
      print("Failed to create the interpreter with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      return nil
    }
    // Load the classes listed in the labels file.
    loadLabels(fileInfo: labelsFileInfo)
  }
```

Comment: Hey Rick, did you able to feed the model with input and get output?